# How to find whether system 390 server is 31 bit or 64 bit

Tags: linux

I have a server running RHEL on s390 hardware. How do I find whether the server is 31 bit or 64 bit?

`uname -a` gives:

```
Linux <hostname> 2.6.32-131.17.1.el6.s390x #1 SMP Thu Sep 29 10:42:48 EDT 2011 s390x s390x s390x GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Running `getconf LONG_BIT` will tell you if it is 64 bit or not:

```
[cole@localhost ~]$getconf LONG_BIT
32
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Wikipedia Page for the S/390](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_ESA/390) it's a 31/32-bit system. The "z" architecture replaced this series and introduced 64-bit.

Comment: On z architecture, would uname -a also read as s390?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea. Have you tried our sister site http://unix.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: Possibly try getconf LONG_BIT - it should tell you if it's 64 or not.

Comment: @Cole `getconf LONG_BIT` prints `64`, which prob. means it's 64 bit. Thanks! Extra points if you phrase that as an answer.

Comment: @BlackSheep I guess this isn't a S/390 then?

Comment: I guess it's system z, but `uname -a` gives s390 as output, so shows how much you can rely on that...

Answer (score 0):

```
uname -m
```

gives you bit size for your server

and you can also use `getconf` command.